# link aggregation with wifi and ethernet on Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-networking, bonding

I have a computer running linux with a wifi and an ethernet interface. I'd like to set up link aggregation (at least fail-over, but other modes would be nice too) between these two so that both this computer, and others on the network see only a single IP address - is this possible?

Comment: Possible, yes... but why would you need this?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but if this works at all, I expect your choices are limited to `active-backup` (aka Mode 1) bonding, with the `fail_over_mac=active` bonding option. See: [bonding.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

This is because almost every WiFi card will not send frames which have a non-local source MAC, and load balancing modes like `balance-xor` and `802.3ad` (aka LACP) want to change the MAC of the device on enslavement.

That being said, I don't really understand what you are protecting against. High Availability from bonding gives protection against link failure. If link goes down on a WiFi NIC, the access point is off, so you're not going to get signal on the other NIC anyway. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯